# How to create a subset of data for geom_density function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a set of data and I want to take a subset of it, then graph it using the geom_density function. When I filter the range from -3 to 3, the resulting graph is larger than 1. I would like to show the percentage of the data that is represented by a score of 0 within this range. Is there a way to do this with geom_density function?

```
score %>%
  filter(zscore <3, zscore  > -3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=zscore)) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[Image showing the density function going above 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBxfF.png)

Comment: Are you asking how to create the subset or how to scale the y-axis to percent? It looks like you've figured out the subset part. This may help with percentages https://stackoverflow.com/a/44189916/3968093

Comment: I think there is a slight confusion here, as densities can easily reach values >1; try `plot(density(rnorm(1000, sd = 0.01)))`. The property of densities is that they integrate to 1, not max out at 1.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that they integrate to 1, I thought it maxed out at 1. Appreciate the help!